# Composer autoload Class not found exception

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I create a file named `Util.php` and there are two class in the `Util.php` file.

- `class StringUtil {}`
- `class ArrayUtil {}`

how can I make the `Util.php` into `composer library` for other project include? now I got a `Class Not Found Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create a file named Util.php and there are two class in the Util.php
>   file.

First of all this is bad practice

Anyway, it can help:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
    }
}
```